# Not able to include the php file in class construct

Tags: php, class

**config.php**

< ?php

```
define('DB_SERVER','localhost');
define('DB_USER','root');
DEFINE('DB_PASSWORD','');
DEFINE('DB','bank');

$conn = new mysqli(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 


?>
```

**edit_action.php**

```
 <?php
    #Edit User code
    print_r($_POST);
    Class edit_user
    {
      public function __construct()
        {
            include 'config.php';

               #including config file
    }
         public function edit()
        {

            print_r($_POST);

               #All the updated code defined here
    }
    }
```

When i try to execute this code it gives error, does not include the config file.

ERROR: Undefined variable: conn in edit_action.php

Comment: Can you share your `config.php`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're submitting your form on action='`edit_action.php`' which only has `print_r($_POST)`, you have not called anything else on this file.

What you can do is add these line on bottom of `edit_action.php`

```
$obj1 = new edit_user;
$obj1->edit();
```

updated code:

```
<?php
#Edit User code
Class edit_user
{
     public function edit()
    {
        include 'config.php';
        print_r($_POST);

           #All the updated code defined here
}
}
$obj1 = new edit_user;
$obj1->edit();
```

**Updated answer as per comment request.**

```
<input type="hidden" value="edit" name='action' />
```

Add this in your form, this will submit your form to `edit()`. You can change this to value to `edit_role` to call `edit_role()`.

**edit_action.php**

```
<?php
    #Edit User code
    Class edit_user
    {
        public function run()
        {
            switch($this->post['action'])
            {
                case 'edit':
                    $this->edit();
                    break;

                case 'edit_role':
                    $this->edit_role();
                    break;
            }
        }

        public function edit()
        {
            include 'config.php';
            print_r($_POST);

               #All the updated code defined here
        }

        public function edit_role()
        {
           #edit_role code goes here
        }
    }

    $obj1 = new edit_user;
    $obj1->run();
```

I hope this will help you.

Happy Coding!

Comment: It did worked but if i  include edit_role() in same class and that needs to include in some other function then in that case both the functions edit() and edit_role() will be include if object is made in same file.

Comment: @JasshhAndrews
Please check updated answer. I hope this will help you. Thanks

Comment: Hey, thanks its working fine. :) :) :)  just one more thing how to include a file  in __construct(). As it gives me error every time.

Comment: @JasshhAndrews can you share  code and error you getting ?

Comment: public function __construct()
                     {
                         include 'config.php';
                       }   ERROR: Undefined variable: conn

Comment: can you just help me how to share updated code in comments. ?

Comment: you can edit the question and add code below your question.

Answer (score 0):

Your are submitting the form on the php file `edit_action.php` where there no call for `(new edit_user())->edit()` so that's why it is just printing `$_POST`

**Change this:**

```
<form class="w3-container " action='edit_action.php' method='post' name="form"  id="form-e" role="form">
```

**This:**

```
<form class="w3-container " action='edit_user.php' method='post' name="form"  id="form-e" role="form">
```